# Is there a way to select all columns for a SELECT statement with JOINs without breaking the entity mapping?

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbc, spring-data-jdbc

I have a `application_user` table with a corresponding `UserEntity` record. Additionally, I have a `user_meta_data` table with a `UserMetaDataEntity` record as a 1:1 relation to the `user`.

```java
@Table("application_user")
record UserEntity(@Id @Nullable Long id,
                  // more columns
                  @Nullable
                  UserMetaDataEntity metaData
) {
// (...)
}
```

Currently, I need to directly write SQL queries, as I have some complex queries at hand that can't be modeled easily via function names. In these queries, I need to explicitly select all columns

```java
@Query("""
        SELECT application_user.ID AS ID, user_meta_data.phoneNumber AS USERMETADATA_PHONE_NUMBER
        FROM application_user
        INNER JOIN user_meta_data ON user_meta_data.user_id = application_user.id
""")
Stream<UserEntity> streamUsersWithMetaData();
```

But I want to avoid explicitly defining column names, as my actual entities have many columns. I would prefer calling `SELECT * FROM application_user INNER JOIN ...` but this doesn't work, as Spring Data JDBC expects the column names to be prefixed with the joined table name.

Is there a way to define custom SQL queries without needing to define all columns in the SELECT statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `SELECT *` but there are at least two ways you can minimise the pain.

Either you define a `static final String` containing the list of columns and concatenate them with the rest of the query.

Alternatively you can specify a `RowMapper` doing the mapping. It could wrap the `ResultSet` and forward the call to the original [`EntityRowMapper`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/blob/main/spring-data-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jdbc/core/convert/EntityRowMapper.java)